# How to call Window.print() on a popup window in NWJS?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nwjs

In NWJS, I would like to open a popup window with a local file URL to a PDF and then print the PDF right away (on Windows). I tried doing this:

```
nw.Window.open(
  'file://' + downloadItem.filename.replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  {new_instance: true, height: 600, width: 800},
  function(pdfWin) {
    pdfWin.on('loaded', function() {
      this.print({autoprint: false});
    });
  }
);
```

But in the developer tools, it says that `pdfWin` is undefined, which is completely weird to me considering that it should work [according to the documentation](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#windowopenurl-options-callback). I then tried using [`Window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) with [nw.Window.get()](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#windowgetwindow_object) and then but I get an error saying `Blocked a frame with origin "chrome-extension://..." from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot open different origin urls. refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @PrabodhM I understand, of course, that cross-origin rules are in effect, but security is a bit different in NWJS: http://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Security%20in%20NW.js/. Anyway, it's really the printing that is the problem.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, sorry as I am not aware of NWJs environment and working. Have you tried opening any file using the same method, maybe hardcoded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the problem. The code above works if you take out `new_instance: true`. If that variable is marked as `true`, then `this` is `undefined` initially and the code doesn't work.